# Mule - JUnit Send requests - Best practice

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mule

This is the `mule flow` that I use to the tests:

```
HTTP Listener > Logger (Message) > HTTP Request POST > Logger (Response)
```

In my **mule project** I have 5 `classes`. This is an example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Car {

    String name;
    String color;

    public Car() {
        super();
    }

    public Car(String name, String color) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
[More Setters and Getters...]
}
```

I asign the element `@XmlRootElement` to `class` and `@XmlElement` to `setters`.

Then, I have a main class when I test the flow with Config Resources:

```
public class JUnitSend extends FunctionalTestCase {

    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "send-xml.xml";
    }      

    public String getName() {
        return "Mule Server Test";
    }

    public Car myCar()
    {       
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.setName("Ferrari");
        myCar.setColor("Red");

        return myCar;
    }

    @Test
    public void sendXML() throws Exception {

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Car.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(myCar(), sw);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();

        MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);

        MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:8090/", xmlString, null);

        assertEquals("Hello", result.getPayloadAsString());
    }
}
```

But I want to test it with the **remaining 4 classes**.

What is the **best practises** to test with the other classes?

Comment: Just an unrelated comment: as a best practice, you should be taking the MuleClient from the MuleContext instead of creating your own. That is ```muleContext.getClient()```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    public class JUnitSend extends FunctionalTestCase {

    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "send-xml.xml";
    }      

    public String getName() {
        return "Mule Server Test";
    }

    public Car myCar()
    {       
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.setName("Ferrari");
        myCar.setColor("Red");

        return myCar;
    }

private String marshallObject(Object object)
{
   JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Car.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(object, sw);
        return sw.toString();
}

    @Test
    public void testSendXml_car() throws Exception {        

        MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);

        MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:8090/", marshallObject(myCar(), null);

        assertEquals("Hello", result.getPayloadAsString());
    }

@Test
    public void testSendXml_otherObject() throws Exception {        

        MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);

        MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:8090/", marshallObject(myOtherObject(), null);

        assertEquals("Hello", result.getPayloadAsString());
    }



}
```

And yes getting `MuleClient` from `context` is slightly more efficient:

```
MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's a nice solution, but if I use a `client.send` with `muleContext.getClient()` it returns me an error `The method send(String, MuleMessage) in the type MuleClient is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)` How can I create a MuleMessage with the string?

Comment: `send(String url, Object payload, Map<String, Object> messageProperties)`  pass 3rd argument as null

Comment: It is **deprecated**, the unique method that I can use is: `send(String url, MuleMessage message)`

Comment: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/modules/client/src/main/java/org/mule/module/client/MuleClient.java see line 552